# What am I missing from my declared structure

Tags: c, function, structure

I get an error for my simple program that's just supposed to add together values in a C structure.
I don't see anything inherently wrong with my code, which I'll paste a little bit down. All the semicolons and brackets seem to be in order, so my question is, what am I missing from the struct declaration.

Error line:

```
Structure.c:7:20: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘struct’
    struct addDistance(struct distance dist1, struct distance dist2){
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct distance{
    float feet;
    float inches;
} dist;

struct addDistance(struct distance dist1, struct distance dist2){
    struct dist3;
    dist3.feet = dist1.feet + dist2.feet;
    dist3.inches = dist1.inches + dist2.inches;
    return dist3;
}
int main(){
    dist dist1;
    dist dist2;

    dist1.feet = 2;
    dist2.feet = 3;
    dist1.inches = 6;
    dist2.inches = 4;
    addDistance(dist1, dist2);
}
```

**Answered below for future reference**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`struct addDistance(struct distance dist1, struct distance dist2){`

should be

`struct distance addDistance(struct distance dist1, struct distance dist2){`

You need to include the whole type for your struct which is `struct distance`, or because you use typedef, your return type could be `dist`. So it could also be

`dist addDistance(struct distance dist1, struct distance dist2){`

When the compiler sees `struct SOME_NAME`, it expects that either `struct SOME_NAME` is a struct that has been declared previously, or that you are declaring it now. So your compiler thinks that you're trying to declare a new struct called `struct addDistance`.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I can't believe I missed something that simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that you wrote `struct` instead of `struct distance` as the return type of the function and as the type of dist3.